# remove sms unsupported characters

Tags: php, regex, sms

is there any preg or str_replace that can help me remove characters from a string that are not supported on sms in phones.
Now accented characters are shown as yy in sms.

Comment: Accented characters should be supported by SMS. I can send/receive them with my phone. Are you sure you're not sending them with the wrong character encoding?

Comment: If all you want to support is Latin characters (From space (32) to ~ (126)), you can use a regex like `/[^\x{0020}-\x{007E}]/u`

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to [transliterate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) those chars.

This will convert an accented `ñ` to a plain `n`.

[Here is useful further reading on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284535/php-transliteration)

Comment: i used iconv but it removes normal string after the asccented chars as well :-(