# Removing special Characters from string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, special-characters

I am using a function for removing special character from strings.

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace('', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

And here is the test case

```
echo clean('a|"bc!@£de^&$f g');
Will output: abcdef-g
```

with Reference from SO Answer.
The problem is what if ' is the last character in my string , Like I get a string `America'` from a excel file ,If I put that in this function, it wouldn't escape `'` .Any help when first and last character is `'`

Comment: Does [this function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230012/replacing-accents-with-their-counterparts/3230193#3230193) do what you need?

Comment: @JohnConde no this is not...

Comment: What are "special" characters?

Comment: So you want to replace ' always or when it is first or last char in the string?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what you need: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: @deceze ' is the character

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "special" characters and what you need this for?

Comment: @user1765876: I don't think "yes" is a valid answer to an A OR B question.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes I want to replace ' when it is either first or last

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try to replace the regular expectation 
change

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);
```

with

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\']/", '', $string);  // escape apostraphe
```

or

you can [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)  It is quicker and easier than [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)  Because it does not use regular expressions.

```
$text = str_replace("'", '', $string);
```

Answer (score 6):

In a more detailed manner from Above example, Considering below is your string:

```
$string = '<div>This..</div> <a>is<a/> <strong>hello</strong> <i>world</i> ! هذا هو مرحبا العالم! !@#$%^&&**(*)<>?:";p[]"/.,\|`~1@#$%^&^&*(()908978867564564534423412313`1`` "Arabic Text نص عربي test 123 و,.m,............ ~~~ ٍ،]ٍْ}~ِ]ٍ}"; ';
```

Code:

```
echo preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 !@#$%^&*().]/u','', strip_tags($string));
```

`Allows:` English letters (Capital and small), 0 to 9 and characters `!@#$%^&*().`

`Removes:` All html tags, and special characters other than above

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance i think that the addslashes function could be a starting point. http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a better pattern out there, but this should work for the entire string:

```
preg_replace("/^'|[^A-Za-z0-9\'-]|'$/", '', $string);
```

If you need to replace them around words in the string you'll have to use \b for word boundaries.  Also, if you want to replace multiples at the start or end you'll need to add a + to those.