# PHP convert cyrillic

Tags: php

**Which method of transliteration is true to convert cyrillic letters to latin letters?**

Like writing russian names using english alphabet.

There are many methods of conversion, searching for one that is used on television or other mass media.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP is asking about transliteration, rather than technical conversion. If so, the answer is that there is not one 'true' mapping. Sorry.

Comment: @user257493: just need to convert russian names to latin letters. Its not about typing messages, about using them in urls.

Comment: @user257493: its called transliteration and there are many maps on it. An example - http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/download/zip/package/2641/name/cyrlat-2005-10-26.zip

Comment: @Colin Fine: yes, but which way is usually used for writing russian names on tvchannels like eurosport? There is some method, they can't invent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take this http://drupal.org/project/transliteration and make it suit your project. This is one of the best implementations of transliteration.

Also you can transliterate using iconv:

```
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

```
mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', $encoding);
```

Comment: This can't be used for cyrillic letters.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for "transliteration", the conversion of text in foreign scripts to latin script, represented to "sound" the same way.

See this question: [PHP Transliteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284535/php-transliteration)

Comment: Call to undefined function  iconv_open()

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at iconv functions:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php

You may be interested in:

- [iconv_set_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-set-encoding.php)
- [iconv_get_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-get-encoding.php)
- [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Comment: I don't need charset encoding. Its different.