# How to convert special characters to normal characters?

Tags: php, preg-replace, special-characters

I am trying to convert characters like:

```
ë, ä, ï, ö, etc.
```

To normal characters like:

```
e, a, i, o, etc.
```

What is the best way to do this?
I've tried many things, like preg_replace and str_replace.

Can someone help me out?

-- EDIT --

What I tried, was:

```
$ts = array("[À-Å]","Æ","Ç","[È-Ë]","/[Ì-Ï]/","/Ð/","/Ñ/","/[Ò-ÖØ]/","/×/","/[Ù-Ü]/","/[Ý-ß]/","/[à-å]/","/æ/","/ç/","/[è-ë]/","/[ì-ï]/","/ð/","/ñ/","/[ò-öø]/","/÷/","/[ù-ü]/","/[ý-ÿ]/");

$tn = array("A","AE","C","E","I","D","N","O","X","U","Y","a","ae","c","e","i","d","n","o","x","u","y");

$title = preg_replace($ts, $tn, $text);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Transliteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284535/php-transliteration)

Comment: The correct term here would be accented characters. Special characters are things like $#@/\ etc.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

try this .. works for me.

```
iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
```

Comment: utf8 and utf-8 didn't work for me. chars get replaced by a question mark, that's all.

Comment: @CREE7EN Try setting the locale first: `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF8');` After that encoding appears to be better.

Comment: I had two strings same identical words strcmp returns value greater then 0 after I used iconv solution strcmp returns 0 which is equal to each other

Comment: The documentation says: "If and how //TRANSLIT works exactly depends on the system's iconv() implementation".

Answer (score 33):

i like stewies' answer, but for completeness this works for me.

```
preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities($foo));
```

Comment: This would work better IMO as it does not depend on the server's locale. I had some issues where `iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);` would work fine locally, but once pushed the results were different, probably because of different server locale.

Comment: @FooBar This seems to be due to the system's iconv implementation. See the iconv documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For example, it is create a simple readable URL from a content title:

```
function cleanurl($title) {
        return urlencode(strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", htmlentities($title)))));
}
```