# How to replace umlaut characters or Unaccent in PHP?

Tags: php, character-encoding, diacritics

I have a name "**GÃ¶ran**" and I want it to be converted to "**Goran**" which means I need to **unaccent** the particular word. But What I have tried doesn't seem to **unaccent** all the words.

This is the code I ve used to Unaccent :

```
private function Unaccent($string)
{
    return preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml|caron);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
}
```

The places where is not working(incorrect matching) : I mean it is not giving the expected result on the right hand side,

```
JÃƒÅ’rgen => Juergen
InÃƒÅ¡s => Ines
```

The place where it is working(correct matching):

```
GÃ¶ran => Goran
JÃ¸rgen Ole => Jorgen
JÃ©rÃ´me => Jerome
```

What could be the reason? How to fix? do you have any better approach to handle all cases?

Comment: found this on the web, useful? http://snipplr.com/view/65596/unaccent-a-string/

Comment: Stop! JÃ©rÃ´me is not a name, it is badly formatted. Jérôme is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

You have two problems:

Firstly. These names are not accented. They are badly formatted.

It seems that you had an UTF-8 file but were working with them using ISO-8559-1. For example if you tell your editor to use ISO-8859-1 and copy-paste the text into a text-area in a browser using UTF-8. Then you saved the badly formatted names in the database. I have seen many such problems arising from copy-paste.

If the names are correctly formatted, then you can solve your second problem. Unaccent them. There is already a question treating this: [How to convert special characters to normal characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9720665/220060)

**Long answer (focuses on the badly formatted accented letters only)**

Why do you have got `GÃ¶ran` when you want `Göran`?

Let's begin with Unicode: The letter `ö` is in Unicode `LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS`. Its Unicode code point is F6 hexadecimal or, respectively, 246 decimal. See this [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f6/index.htm) to the Unicode database.

In ISO-8859-1 code points from 0 to 255 are left as is. The small letter o with diaeresis is saved as only one byte: 246.

UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 treat the code points 0 to 127 (aka ASCII) the same. They are left as is and saved as only one byte. They differ in the treatment of the code points 128 to 255. UTF-8 can encode the whole Unicode code point set, while ISO-8859-1 can only cope with the first 256 code points.

So, what does UTF-8 do with code points above 128? There is a staggered set of encoding possibilities for code points as they get bigger and bigger. For code points up to 2047 two bytes suffice. They are encoded like this: ([see this bit schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description))

```
x xxxx xxxx xxxx => 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

Let's encode small letter o with diaresis in UTF-8. The bits are: `0 0000 1111 0110` and gets encoded to `11000011 10110110`. This is nice.

However, these two bytes can be misunderstood as two **valid** (!) ISO-8559-1 bytes. What are `11000011` (C3 hex) and `10110110` (B6 hex)? Let's consult [an ISO-8859-1 table](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~stolfi/EXPORT/www/ISO-8859-1-Encoding.html). C3 is Capital A tilde, and B6 is Paragraph sign. Both signs are valid and no software can detect this misunderstanding by just looking at the bits.

It **definitively** needs people who know what names look like. `GÃ¶ran` is just not a name. There is an uppercase letter smack in the middle of the name and the paragraph sign is not a letter at all. Sadly, this misunderstanding does not stop here. Because all characters are valid, they can be copy-pasted and re-rendered. In this process the misunderstanding can be repeated again. Let's do this with `Göran`. We already misunderstood it once and got a badly formatted `GÃ¶ran`. The letter Capital A, tilde and the paragraph sign render to two bytes in UTF-8 **each** (!) and are interpreted as four bytes of gobbledygook, something like `GÃƒÅ.ran`.

Poor Jürgen! The umlaut `ü` got mistreated twice and we have `JÃƒÅ’rgen`.

We have a terrible mess with the umlauts here. It's even possible that the OP got this data as is from his customer. This happened to me once: I got mixed data: well formatted, badly formatted once, twice and thrice in the same file. It's extremely frustrating.

Comment: help me on how to fix the problem and unaccent. @nalply

Comment: the viewing type has no effect on the internal data PHP is dealing with. That is a browser issue.

Comment: @ohmusama: No, that's not true. If you configure your editor with ISO-8859-1, then you get these badly formatted names.

Comment: Actually the thing I am doing was that I am unaccenting the word and looking for the exact match with the word on the right hand side and I am not getting exact match for the words I mentioned in my question. @nalply

Answer (score 6):

This might be what you are looking for

[How to convert special characters to normal characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720665/how-to-convert-special-characters-to-normal-characters)

but use "utf-8" instead.

```
$text = iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: This answer is not going to help the OP.