# How to convert Á to A

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert Ágætis character to normal letters but getting �g�tis.

```
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $CDTitle);
echo "<div> 
<a href = \"editCDForm.php?itemCode=$iCDID\">$CDTitle</a> 
</div>\n";
echo "</td><td>";   
echo $row['CDYear'];
echo "</TD></tr>";
```

Comment: Á is a normal letter.  Converting it to **A** is like converting **a** to **z**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, the below help to resolve converting the character

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $CDTitle);
```

[How to convert special characters to normal characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720665/how-to-convert-special-characters-to-normal-characters)

Comment: I try that but i got -> Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input stringecho. I was also trying with -> setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8'); but  it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720665/how-to-convert-special-characters-to-normal-characters) Try php `iconv`

```
echo iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', 'Ágætis');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/461431)

> iconv — Convert string to requested character encoding
>
> string iconv ( string $in_charset , string $out_charset , string $str
>   )