# Can't replace × by str_replace

Tags: php

this is my code:

```
$content = str_replace("×", "x", $content);
```

The problem that i can replace any word but I can't replace something like × how can solve this issue ?

Be known that × is not x letter it's a symbol.

Comment: But it worked .

Comment: @Mohammad It's working with any Symbols yea except × don't know why can you try to replace × with anything ?

Comment: The above snippet works for me

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I will try anther solutions to solve my problem I can replace any Symbols except × don't know what's the wrong but thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called transliteration, heres a similar thread:
[How to convert special characters to normal characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720665/how-to-convert-special-characters-to-normal-characters)

this may work:

```
$content = iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $content);
```

I'm not sure why your approach isn't working for you because I tested it on phpfiddle.org, and this works:

```
<?php
$content = "some string with × symbol";
$content = str_replace("×", "x", $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

I also tested
  `preg_replace` on:
http://www.phpliveregex.com
and this works:

```
preg_replace("/×/", "x", $input_lines);
```

Its always best to wrap strings in single quotes when they don't have special characters intended to be interpreted by PHP. If this issue is due to PHP interpreting the × symbol for some reason, this will fix it:

```
$content = str_replace('×', "x", $content);
```

Comment: Special characters within single quotes won't be parsed at all (backslash or not). They will be kept as written. I don't really see the point of using `preg_replace()` instead of `str_replace()` in this case. What would regular expressions bring to the table (except overhead) when just replacing a literal string?

Comment: Thank you, I solve my problem by check the page source then I found that it appears as &#215; so I add $content = str_replace("&#215;", "x", $content); and it's working find now.

Comment: Magnus: Point taken about preg_replace, playing around with the flexibility can help narrow things down though. About the quotes, thats what I mean, when the string is not meant to be parsed, single quotes should be used. I meant backslashes themselves are the only thing that gets parsed, i.e. $str = '\'; will cause a parse error since the backslash will escape the closing quote.