# What characters are allowed as a shortcode tag and what sanitizing filter should I used for them?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, sanitization, shortcode

I working on a plugin where the user can define shortcode tags. What would you suggest to allow, my thought is only allow ascii characters.

Also, how do you sanitize the input? I'm thinking maybe `stip_tags` and then regex to allow only `a-z, 0-9` or is there a better solution? Maybe wordpress filter would work? Or could I maybe use the filter wordpress uses for slugs?

Comment: never heard of them, that's why i asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this-is-a-good-slug**
Meaning you must allow also an hyphen (-)

after this you need to call the following:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/","",$string);    // strip away everything except a-z,0-9 and hyphen
$string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/"," ",$string);     // clean multiple dashes or whitespaces
$string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/","-",$string);           // convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
```

be careful; you need ALSO to change UTF8 character into ascii/latin, meaning you NEED to [transliterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284535/php-transliteration) in other languages containing such characters.

Comment: what happens when i am not change utf-8 to ascii?

Comment: actaully wordpress has issues with hyphens! [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53120/15642]

Comment: About utf8; a shortcut must be (in my opinion) in latin so anyone can use them. About hyphens:  just change the last preg_replace to "/[\s-]/" to get rid of hyphens but leave underscores. About transliteration:  check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284535/php-transliteration)

Comment: well i know a little regex and how to get them away thank you, since i just use a very simple solution to only accept 3 chars of alphanumeric with maximal one underscore at a time now i guess i don't have to deal with transliteration. thanks