# Working with paths using special characters in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters

**My question is:** how can/should I create a directory, test if exists and get it's contents using special characters in the name?

**My scenario:** I need to create a directory, put some images there, and then get that directory contents. That directory may contain a special characters. For example **`galería`**

When creating the directory with `mkdir()`, the name changed to **`galerÃ­a`**. So the solution that worked for me was to `utf8_decode()` the string.

So far so good...

I upload images to that directory...

Then I attempted to scan the directory doing:

```
$gallery = [];

if(is_dir($path)) //$path contains a valid path including my recently created directory
{
    $gallery = glob("$path*{.jpg,.gif,.png}", GLOB_BRACE);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($gallery);
echo "</pre>";
```

But `is_dir()` returned false. So I had to do this to get inside the if statement:

```
$path = mb_convert_encoding($path, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
```

Now `is_dir()` works, but `glob()` doesn't. At this point I should mention that after `mb_convert_encoding()`, the name I'm getting is **`galer�a`**

Any help?

**EDIT:** If I use **`pictures`** for directory name, I don't need to use `utf8_decode()` neither `mb_convert_encoding()`. `mk_dir()`, `is_dir()` and `glob()` work flawlessly

Comment: did you try mb_internal_encoding('utf-8'); ?

Comment: @ziollek: What I've tried is what I posted plus a combination of utf8_encode, utf8_decode, urlencode, and urldecode functions mixed together. I will search for the function you suggest

Comment: [some relevant reading material for you](http://evertpot.com/filesystem-encoding-and-php/): as soon as you step out of the ascii-range, it is varies per OS (and filesystem).

Comment: @Wrikken: I was starting to think something like that. I'm currently developing in Windows 7 and was wondering if the same happens in Linux. If that's the case: is there a cross-platform solution?

Comment: @Wrikken: Should I "simply urlencode all your filenames before writing them to disk" like the article says? Although urlencode() aint doing it for me

Comment: Well, I mainly linked to it to show you the issues between operating systems. I have never had a real reason to step outside ascii for path or filenames. Ever. `urlencode()`-ing them isn't very elegant in my opinion, I usually just cast it to ascii with `iconv`, and query & link them by that name. If you _need_ to make a distinction between the directory 'gap' & 'gäp', well, good luck, but I personally would usually find the ascii solution for it.

Comment: Solution: don't use special characters in file/folder names. It is a nightmare without end.

Comment: @Sammitch: I'm starting to see that, but I must support Spanish characters like á, ü and ñ

Comment: Must you? Replace them with [transliteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284535/php-transliteration) to conform to ASCII naming convention, and append a short hash of the original name to prevent collisions. eg `Matías -> Matias-56dbe8b4` where the hash is from `dechex(crc32("Matías"))`