# PHP function that translates, e.g., "æ" into "ae" and vice versa?

Tags: php, encoding, character

Is there a PHP function that translates ligatures like "Æ" into "AE" and *vice versa*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Transliteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284535/php-transliteration)

Comment: You can always build your own if it's not going to be too intensive. A simple `preg_replace()` or similar function can do this quite easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iconv` with "`//TRANSLIT`" works very well:

```
$strWithoutLigatures = iconv("utf-8", "us-ascii//TRANSLIT", $strWithLigatures);
```

([source](https://drupal.org/node/63924))

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of a few of PHP's functions, one being the [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) function.

```
<?php

$replace='Æ';
$new=str_replace('Æ', 'AE', $replace); 

echo $new;
```

Will echo **AE**

---

Vice-versa would be:

```
<?php

$replace='AE';
$new=str_replace('AE', 'Æ', $replace); 

echo $new;
```

Will echo **Æ**

---

Using the [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function, it can be used in sentences, such as:

```
echo str_replace("Æ","AE","Æ has been replaced from using: ") . "Æ";
```

Which will echo **AE has been replaced from using: Æ**