# How to actually work with PHP Transliterator (Romanization) in order to convert Farsi to Finglish

Tags: php, farsi

I have tried everything but it does not seem to work.
This code is suppose to work with any Latin Character:

```
var_dump(transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; Lower()', "A æ Übérmensch på høyeste nivå! И я люблю PHP! ﬁ"));
```

should output this:

```
// string(41) "a ae ubermensch pa hoyeste niva! i a lublu php! fi"
```

but even this does not work for me to convert Latin to English.
To clarify, I have:

```
$word = "سلام";
```

I need this output (literally character sounds in English, or Finglish):

```
//salam
```

Comment: Does this assist you in your goal? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284535/php-transliteration

Comment: Unfortunately not.